# Origin of heat kernel regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory

One of the ones the make the infinite vacuum zero point energy finite is to use the [heat kernel regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization#Heat_kernel_regularization).
Does anyone know the origin of this method? Or the first paper published discussing such a model?

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization#History)?

Comment: Right under the linked Wikipedia section it says:"*Much of the early work establishing the convergence and equivalence of series regularized with the heat kernel and zeta function regularization methods was done by G. H. Hardy and J. E. Littlewood in 1916*".